# How to show the names of non-participants in the all last sending quizzes in each division?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing a training management web-based system that provides the user with short quizzes to refresh their knowledge. Anyway, I have the following database design:

```
Employee Table: Username, Name, DivisionCode
Divisions Table: SapCode, DivisionShortcut
Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, IsSent
Question Table: QuestionID, Question, QuizID...
UserQuiz Table: UserQuizID, QuizID, Username, Score.
```

I was be able to come up with a query that shows the names of all non-participants in all divisions just in the last quiz. What I want now is to show the non-participants names in all quizzes that have been sent to the users to participate in them. The results should be listed grouping by quiz title and DivisionShortcut. **So how to do that?**

My Query:

```
SELECT d.DivisionShortcut, e.Name 
FROM employee e
 join Divisions d on (e.DivisionCode = d.SapCode)
 left join (select A.QuizID, a.Username 
            from UserQuiz a join 
                 (select max(QuizID) QuizID from dbo.Quiz where IsSent=1) b
                       on a.QuizId = b.QuizID ) c
                                 on e.Username = c.Username
                                 WHERE c.QuizID is null
                                 Order By d.DivisionShortcut
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CROSS JOIN` to get all combinations of employee and Quiz, then use `NOT EXISTS` to eliminate all combinations that have been completed:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Employee e
        INNER JOIN Divisions d
            ON e.DivisionCode = d.SapCode
        CROSS JOIN Quiz
WHERE   Quiz.IsSent = 1 
AND     NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    UserQuiz uq
            WHERE   uq.QuizID = Quiz.QuizID
            AND     uq.UserName = e.UserName
        )
```